# The font of a stylesheeted spinbox cannot be resized

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

Modifying the fontsize of a `QSpinBox` has no effect if a stylesheet was applied to it, while all the other widget classes I tested are resized properly regardless of their stylesheet. `QSpinBox`es without a stylesheet are also resized properly. Note that all the widgets' `.font().pointSize()` are equal so I think this is only a display issue.

A possible workaround would be to save the current stylesheet, set it to None temporarily, resize the font and restore the stylesheet but that sounds horrible and hacky.

I am using Python 3.7.4 and PyQt5 5.12.2.

This is how my MRE looks:

[image]

Below is the code which was used:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton, QSpinBox, QMainWindow
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Setup widgets.
        self.widgets = []

        for n in range(2):
            label = QLabel(parent=self)
            label.move(10+150*n, 20)
            label.setText("QLabel")
            setattr(self, f"label{n+1}", label)

            pb = QPushButton(parent=self)
            pb.move(10+150*n, 60)
            pb.setText("QPushButton")
            setattr(self, f"pb{n+1}", pb)

            le = QLineEdit(parent=self)
            le.move(10+150*n, 100)
            le.setText("QLineEdit")
            setattr(self, f"le{n+1}", le)

            sb = QSpinBox(parent=self)
            sb.move(10+150*n, 140)
            sb.setSpecialValueText("QSpinBox")
            setattr(self, f"sb{n+1}", sb)

            for widget in (label, pb, le, sb):
                self.widgets.append(widget)

        # Take note of the initial window size.
        self.initial_size = (self.width(), self.height(), 30)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        # Paint the right-hand side widgets in red.
        for widget in self.widgets[int(len(self.widgets)/2):]:
            class_name = widget.__class__.__name__ # QLabel, QPushButton, QSpinBox.
            widget.setStyleSheet(class_name + "{background-color: red}")



    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        """Adjust the fontsize of all the widgets upon resizing the main window."""

        # Calculate a scale factor by comparing current and initial size.
        w0, h0, f0 = self.initial_size
        w, h = self.width(), self.height()
        scale = min(w/w0, h/h0)

        # Apply the scale factor to each widget font.
        for widget in self.widgets:
            font = widget.font()
            font.setPointSize(scale * f0)
            widget.setFont(font)

        # Check that all fontsizes are identical.
        assert len(set(widget.font().pointSize() for widget in self.widgets)) == 1



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setAttribute(Qt.AA_DisableHighDpiScaling) # Because it's irrelevant here.
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(True)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever a stylesheet is set to a widget, Qt automatically disables that widget's palette and font propagation. This means that all *child* widget will not be notified about font (and palette) changes from the parent.

This is explained in the [inheritance](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html) chapter of the stylesheet syntax:

> In classic CSS, when font and color of an item is not explicitly set, it gets automatically inherited from the parent. By default, when using Qt Style Sheets, a widget does **not** automatically inherit its font and color setting from its parent widget.

Note that the above obviously refers to fonts set using `setFont()` and colors set using `setPalette()`. If you set a font or a color *in* the stylesheet, the propagation of *those* properties will work as expected according to the *cascading* nature of stylesheets.

QSpinBox, like other widgets such as QComboBox and item views, is a *complex* widget, that use children widgets to display and interact with it, and in this case it's a QLineEdit (accessible through [`lineEdit()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractspinbox.html#lineEdit)).

In order to solve your issue there are multiple approaches available:

1. set the `AA_UseStyleSheetPropagationInWidgetStyles` attribute *on the application*:

   ```
   QApplication.setAttribute(
       Qt.AA_UseStyleSheetPropagationInWidgetStyles, True)
   ```

   This obviously has the side effect that the propagation will work for **all** widgets of the application, it's up to you to decide if that is fine or not.
   Note: this attribute has been introduced from Qt 5.7.
2. check if the widget is a QSpinBox and set the font for its line edit:

   ```
   for widget in self.widgets:
       font = widget.font()
       font.setPointSize(scale * f0)
       if isinstance(widget, QSpinBox):
           widget.lineEdit().setFont(font)
       else:
           widget.setFont(font)
   ```
3. set the font with the stylesheet. In your case, you could check if the widget has a stylesheet and use a template to update it:

   ```
   baseStyleSheet = '''
   {} {{
       background-color: red;
       font-size: {}px;
   }}
   '''

   # ...
       def resizeEvent(self, event):
           w0, h0, f0 = self.initial_size
           w, h = self.width(), self.height()
           scale = min(w/w0, h/h0)
           font_size = scale * f0

           for widget in self.widgets:
               if widget.styleSheet():
                   widget.setStyleSheet(baseStyleSheet.format(
                       widget.__class__.__name__, font_size))
               else:
                   font = widget.font()
                   font.setPointSize(font_size)
                   widget.setFont(font)
   ```

Obviously the above works only in this specific situation where only simple properties are set.

Comment: Thank you for this very complete answer! Solution 2 seems the most elegant to me, as I can just hide the details in my automated resizing functions (the MRE is only the bare bones version of them) and cover all the cases, not just spinboxes, if solution 1 does not fit.

Comment: @Guimoute consider that you could even try to check for children widgets using `for child in widget.findChildren(QWidget): child.setFont(font)`, which will ensure that the font is set for other complex widgets, like the popup of comboboxes or the headers of item views.